# Номера сегментов в списке воспроизведения HLS

Tags: аудио, hls, m3u

Предположим, что у меня есть список воспроизведения HLS: https://digitacdn.akamaized.net/hls/live/629243/radiosuomipop/master-128000.m3u8.
Он содержит ссылки на сегменты аудио файла в кодировке AAC. Содержимое файла:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
## Created with Z/IPStream R/2 v1.03.23
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:3230447
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2018-11-09T12:57:20Z
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230447.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230448.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230449.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230450.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230451.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01616/seg128000-03230452.aac
```

Что должно произойти, когда путь до сегмента станет следующим: 99999/seg128000-99999999.aac? Какой номер будет у следующего сегмента?

Answer (score 1):

[Спецификация HLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-2) не оговаривает формат URL отдельных сегментов, они могут и вовсе не содержать номера (реальный номер сегмента в потоке определяется как `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE + <порядковый номер в списке>`). То, что у вас URL содержит номер - это особенность конкретного серверного ПО. Каким будет URL у следующего сегмента тоже могут сказать только разработчики этого ПО.